# Publish problem in Websphere Portal 6.1 server on WAS 7 in RAD 7.5

Tags: websphere, portal, rad

I use Websphere Portal 6.1 server on WAS 7 in RAD 7.5 for my web application development. When ever i do change in Java/JSP files i need to publish. Without publishing(Right Click on server and select "Publish"), changes are not reflecting. I have checked with my friends whom have same server settings as mine, but for them its not required to publish. Its painful to "Publish" even i do single change. Any idea how to resolve this?.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server configuration set to use automatic publishing?

From the "Servers" view, double-click your server configuration and look for the "Automatic Publishing" settings.

If this is not the problem, then make sure you run the latest RAD 7.5 fixpack level (currently 7.5.5.1). I actually had a similar problem a while ago and opened a PMR for it, which was fixed at some point between RAD 7.5 and RAD 7.5.5.1.